# Gitlab Runner removes dist folder

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab runner on windows and runner is removing my artifact before my deploy stage is called

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.7.1 (b9bba623)
  on Gitlab runner 8953950b
Using Shell executor...
Running on DZIVOPC...
Fetching changes...
Removing dist/
Removing node_modules/
```

Why is this happening.

From documnetation

Artifacts:

> You can only use paths that are within the project workspace. To pass artifacts between different jobs, see dependencies.

Then in dependencies:

> Note that artifacts from all previous stages are passed by default.

I have tried both with and without and with cache and without.
Still nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was in the

`cache_dir` variable. It was renamed in the newer versions so it wasn't set.

Answer (score 1):

Add at the end of your gitlab-ci:

```
cache:
  untracked: true
```